# How to make a users table the easiest to search through in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a question I would like to ask about a database I'm designing. I have one table that stores all user information, contains 12 columns including the email and password fields. I want to make this table efficient for searching. I'm looking at multiple options in doing this.

1. Have the user table have a primary key on the email value
   I only have one table with the email values, so if emails are changed I don't have to worry about updating a bunch of tables.
2. Have the user table have both a user id primary key that's auto incremented and a key on the email
   I need to put a key on the email because when the user logs in, they user their email.
3. Have a separate "registration" table that contains an index on both the email and an auto incremented user id.
   I can then join this table to a user values table that uses the userid as a foreign key.

Which of these options will be most efficient if there a large number of users? (>100,000) I want to design it right from the start so that I don't have to redesign once I see performance issues. My intuition says having a 3rd table "registration" with just those two values would be most effective, so that I don't have to use a string comparison when looking for the bulk of the user data. But I'm not 100% sure.

I've looked through other questions and didn't get a definate answer for my type of situation. I considered the options I found and integrated my thoughts of each type above.

Comment: Could you post the layout of the table you do have? I suspect your table could use a good normalizing, but the details depend on the starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table with only 12 (assuming related columns) does not stand out as an automatic candidate for normalizing.  If you over-normalize, you will just have to undo your work down the road due to performance issues and over-complicated queries. The whole point of a relational database is to have similar information in the same table so that you don't have to `JOIN` on every query!

Adding an index to any columns being searched (certainly on your `'email'` column!) is the first route to take to optimize `WHERE` clause performance on your tables. And 100,000+ rows is not considered large by modern database standards.

If after adding indexes on all frequently scanned columns, you still desire more performance, you should consider other optimizations more related to the database engine. For example, using the MyISAM table format with `ROW_FORMAT = FIXED` can offer drastic improvements over InnoDB. The prerequisites would be to not use any variable-length fields (`CHAR()` instead of `VARCHAR()`), and that this table would be read much more than it is inserted to or deleted from (because the latter options do use table-level locking as opposed to row-level locking in MyISAM-based tables).  But the user information table is not likely deleted from or inserted to very often (compared to the number of reads/selects), and also a fixed maximum of 100 or 200 chars could easily be used for name/email/address/etc. fields, so it is likely a great candidate. Here is an [article](http://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/2012/09/mysql-optimization-faster-selects-myisam-fixed-row-format) showing a 44% speedup from making this change.

Only after all these steps, should you then consider over-normalization or table partitioning or other such schemes.